# Upto how many numbers next_permutation (given in CPP <algorithm>)works?

Tags: c++

I am using next_permutation in cpp (algorithm library). What is the upper limit on the length of the string which it can permute? As i can permute a string of length 5 easily but for length 50 it's just do not stop. I know 50! is quite large so i want to know if there is some reasonable limit on it's usage.

Comment: Wait a bit more, it will stop eventually.

Comment: Just wait for 10^45 years (or something around that order).

Comment: @H2CO3 I was using this function with some other logic in my problem. May be because of the algo which i was using was a bit slow to use, it wasn't stopping. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Well it works for as many numbers as your memory will fit. It simply takes longer. And by longer I mean that for 50! you will have to wait about `96442456880115988215412887386050129516671872047` **years** on a contemporary computer or a lot of orders of magnitute longer then the universe is supposed to exist.